# keep dataTable present through page navigating aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

i have data Table which is dynamically created and is bind to grid View and the page have a button which is redirecting user on another page when is clicked. That's page one.Now when user is redirected on page 2, and if he want to get back on page 1, I want to be present  data Table when page load.Some example code how to do that?

**page1**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
    GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable();
    GridView2.DataBind();
 }

 public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
      Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
 }
  //method for insert dataTable in database
public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
     dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
            Session["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;
            dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)Session["Markici"];
            GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertMarkica",conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "InsertMarkica";
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtCurrentTable.Rows)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirmaID", dr["FirmaID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Godina", dr["Godina"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kasa", dr["KasaID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Masa", dr["Masa"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarkicaID", dr["MarkicaID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", dr["Datum"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VrabotenID", dr["VrabotenID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Smena", dr["Smena"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VkIznos", dr["VkIznos"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VkDanok", dr["VkDanok"]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
            }
```

**page2**

```
public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Reponse.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
   //Now when is redirected on page1, it should be present data Tale,
   //needed that data Table for inserting records in database
}
```

Comment: You can use `Session` to keep data .

Comment: please example, I don't have idea how to do that.

Comment: Put some code in the question so that it can be changed accordingly.

Comment: Session["someKey"] = myDataTable - be warned though, DataTables are heavy objects. be efficient.

Comment: ViewState is for page state, you should use Session state

Comment: remember though, session can expire after the predefined or set value in your config file (default is 20 mins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a session variable as follow

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
    Session["Markici"]=dtCurrentTable;
    GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable();
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Not the value of `Session["Markici"]` will be available in the current session on any page. You need to cast and use it as follow

```
 dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)Session["Markici"];
```

Comment: and now when i try to insert that data Table in database, it give me an error:  ""Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FirmaID', table 'KasaEP.dbo.Markici'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.  """                                                          all columns are with values, i cannot understand why it give me this error

Comment: OK, so what the user is not came back for 20 min, session will be expire, and user will lost the table...